# How much of The Language of Thorns is canon?

Tags: grishaverse

*The Language of Thorns* is a book of short stories or fairy tales by Leigh Bardugo. While some of them seem that they might be freestanding, others clearly have elements from the  Grishaverse (that is, the Shadow and Bone trilogy and so forth). For example, the narration mentions locations such as Ketterdam, and nationalities or ethnicities such as Suli.

However, some elements of the stories seem to be very different from the sorts of magic seen in the Grishaverse (for example, the candy-magic, or the beast’s power), while others seem as if they might (in-universe) have been inspired by the actions of the Grisha (such as the story of “Little Knife”). In particular, the first story, “Ayama and the Thorn Wood,” seems to have no connection with the Grishaverse at all. On the other hand, the back jacket also confidently declares the book to be part of the Grishaverse.

What elements of this book are part of the Grishaverse?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Leigh Bardugo theses stories are "meant to serve as part of the mythology and folklore of the world".

> *How do these stories fit into the rest of the Grishaverse? Are they kinds of stories the characters in Six of Crows have heard growing up?*
>
> Yes, that’s exactly what they are. **These are stories that are meant to serve as part of the mythology and folklore of the world.** The stories we tell each other and the stories we tell about heroism, about magic, about faith — those things say a lot about who we are and the kind of lessons that we wanna convey to our children. But I hope they also connect to our world too in some of the themes and in some of the ways they play with fear and magic and beauty.
>
> <sup>[Cosmopolitan, Author Leigh Bardugo on Exploring the Dark Side of Fairy Tales in The Language of Thorns](https://www.cosmopolitan.com/entertainment/books/a12475898/leigh-bardugo-language-of-thorns-interview/)</sup>

Comment: I assume the wikia is wrong when it claims some to be companion stories rather than in universe folklore according to the above quote from the author.

Comment: This is right, of course, but there is more to it than this. For example, how does the first story fit in as folklore and mythology? Which culture is it from?

Comment: @Adamant Like I said before I don't really know anything about this universe but I'll have a look to see if there is anything else I can add.

Comment: With the revelations in the *Nikolai* duology, has any of this changed?

Comment: This answer is presumably out-of-date. In the Nikolai duology, the Darkling claims to have met his half-sister long ago, meaning that he is probably the half-brother from the story of Ulla. He would fit the profile. I feel like I remember a story about the Bodymaker as well.